# Segmentation Fault Clarification

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Why do A and B result in segmentation fault. Because even though x has not been assigned a value, it technically still has a garbage value right? Also, why is D not a segmentation fault? My answer key says A and B are segmentation fault but that just seems wrong. D should be the one with a segmentation fault because it is trying to return 0. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong.

A.

```
    int x; 
    int* p = &x;
    cout << p << *p << endl;
```

B.

```
  int* p = new int;
  cout << p << *p <<endl;
```

C.

```
  int* p;
  cout << p << *p <<endl;
```

D.

```
  int* p = 0;
  cout << p << *p <<endl;
```

Comment: C is undefined bahviour, so it could be a seg fault or maybe not. Or both. D sure causes one, because it's dereferencing a null pointer. A and B are fine, I think. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: For D instead of `0` you might want to use `nullptr` for a better clarification.

Comment: *"My answer key says A and B are segmentation fault"* But does it segfault *for you*? Did you try running it?

Comment: yes, I tried running. Both A and B returned garbage addresses while only D returned a seg fault.

Comment: @miBo777 When UB is invoæved, just running the code and observing the result is not a valid approach. A different compiler may do something else. The same compiler on a different platform may do something else. A different version of the same compiler may do something else. Besides, both "garbage value" and "segfault" is a valid result of UB. As would be "doing nothing at all", "printing 0", "printing PI" or *anything* else. There are, quite literally, *no* guarantees about the behaviour. Stop trying to reason about UB, it's impossible.

Comment: To clarify, this was a a multiple choice question... so I'm not trying to reason anything, I'm just trying to seek some clarification regarding this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do A and B result in segmentation fault.

While both are reading uninitialized value from `*p`, which is undefined behavior, *neither* will produce a segmentation fault on any current system.

Both C and D also have undefined behavior, and *may* produce a segmentation fault on current machines with certain compilers and certain optimization options. A segmentation fault isn't guaranteed, but quite likely here.

> This was a question on a practice test that asked, which of these results in a Segmentation Fault. And the answer key said it was A and B.

You must have inverted the meaning of the question (e.g. "which of these *does not* result in a segmentation fault"), or the answer key is wrong.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It tries to assign meaning, and expectations about the outcome, to code with Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

"even though x has not been assigned a value, it technically still has a garbage value right?" - *Wrong*. It has an indeterminate value and reading it is UB.

Reading an uninitialised variable is Undefined Behaviour. You are *not* allowed to do that, and as a result of doing so, the entire program is invalid and has no meaning.  See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

In your examples, A is UB because printing `*p` reads the value of `x` which is uninitialised. B is UB because the `int` pointed to by `p` is uninitialised. C is UB because `p` is uninitialised. D is UB because `*p` dereferences a `nullptr`.

All your examples are invalid code and the compiler is allowed to generate whatever result it wants and it does not have to tell you that you did anything wrong. It's your responsibility to know all the rules of the language and follow them at all times.

Additional recommended reading material:

[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #2/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html)

[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #3/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)

[Undefined Behavior in 2017](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1520)

[A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 1](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)

[A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 2](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/226)

[A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 3](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/232)

Comment: but undefined behavior may or may not result in segmentation fault right?

Comment: @miBo777 UB may result in *anything*. There are *no* requirements on the result.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Do you have a reference for "Reading an uninitialised variable is Undefined Behaviour"? I see many such claims, but cannot find a reference to the C++ standard/working draft.

Comment: This was a question on a practice test that asked, which of these results in a Segmentation Fault. And the answer key said it was A and B. Hence why I was confused.

Comment: This answer is wrong in that neither A nor B will produce a segmentation fault on any current system (though *in theory* they could).

Comment: @EmployedRussian There is *no* guarantee *anywhere* that either option will result in a segmentation fault. Nor is there *any* guarantee that they won't *all* result in a segfault. That's the nature of UB - *any* result is OK. The code (and the test OP took) is simply *wrong* and you cannot reason about the expected output.